# How to access my "Outgoing E-Mail Settings" from code?

Tags: development, visual-studio, central-administration

Is it possible for me to pull the values that are in:

`Central Admin -> System Settings -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings`

from my code behind using the object model?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure that you have already configured the “Outgoing e-mail settings”.

```
//Get the site ID
Guid siteID = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
protected string GetSMTPHostName()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
    {
      //Get the SMTP host name from “Outgoing e-mail settings”
      return site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Parent.Name;
    }
}
protected string GetFromEmailID()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
    {
      //Get the “from email address” from “Outgoing e-mail settings”
      return site.WebApplication.OutboundMailSenderAddress;

    }
}

   //you can also get other properties similarly...
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, look for properties of SPAdministrationWebApplication, you can access it using SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local. Properties are:

OutboundMailCodePage

OutboundMailReplyToAddress

OutboundMailSenderAddress

OutboundMailServiceInstance

OutboundSmsServiceAccount

---

Namespace:  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration

Assembly:  Microsoft.SharePoint (in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)

If you want to update the settings, you need to call UpdateMailSettings method.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint you can configure the outgoing email settings at two locations in the Central Admin.

- First, there is a global setting at `Central Admin -> System Settings -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings` (that is what was asked in the original question).
- Second, you can configure an alternative setting for each of the web applications at `Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage web applications -> (select the web application you would like to configure) -> (select the General Settings drop-down button at the ribbon) -> Outgoing E-mail`.

Via the code from Falak Mahmood you can access this later one.

If you need to access the global settings, you can do it either via the [SPGlobalAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spglobaladmin_members.aspx) class:

```
var globalAdmin = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPGlobalAdmin()
var smtpServer = globalAdmin.OutboundSmtpServer
var mailFromAddress = globalAdmin.MailFromAddress
var mailReplyToAddress = globalAdmin.MailReplyToAddress
```

Or you can access the corresponding properties of the `SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local` instance (of type `SPAdministrationWebApplication`,  subtype of `SPWebApplication`), like `OutboundMailSenderAddress` or `OutboundMailReplyToAddress`.

Note, that the mail related properties of `SPGlobalAdmin` are available only as getter methods. If you want to change them, you can either call the [UpdateMailSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.updatemailsettings.aspx) method:

```
SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.UpdateMailSettings("smtp.company.com", "spsender@company.com", "noreply@company.com", 65001);
```

or set the corresponding properties directly, like

```
var localAdminWebApp = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
localAdminWebApp.Local.OutboundMailSenderAddress = "spsender@company.com";
localAdminWebApp.OutboundMailReplyToAddress = "noreply@company.com";
localAdminWebApp.Update();
```